# NodeJS - Where To Keep Node Config Data?

Tags: node.js

I have written two node scripts running on Mac/Unix which invoke rest services.  Each script requires some configuration information like endpoints, keys, secrets, passwords etc.  Not sure how this information should be stored or passed to the node scripts? I'm new to node and not sure where this type of information is typically stored for a node application.   Its really just a bunch of scripts that I intend to call periodically, so these are not services but scripts that invoke services.

Comment: Wherever you want... use JSON for your config files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like node-config module is the way to go:

```
 https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config
```